# Unable to repartition load query of hive in spark streaming application through SparkSession

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to load data into an external hive table through load query from a specific location.

`SparkSession sqlContext = null;
sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.Builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
String query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/user/outputfiles/P20170613097' INTO TABLE table1 PARTITION (p1='20170613',p2='P2017061301')";
sqlcontext.sql(query);`

finally the partition P2017061301 in hive table collects the data, and this partition doesn't contain evenly distributed partition file with even size but rather like:

part-m-00000 125 KB

part-m-00001 763 KB

part-m-00002 28,171 KB

part-m-00003 68 KB and so on

In order to improve efficiency of the table, I was trying to repartition the data before loading it into hive table using `"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=10"` but this is not working. Any help towards this please?